# LXDE: theme that works for both gtk2 and gtk3?

Tags: lxde

I installed LXDE, but it seems the default theme (ClearLooks) doesn't work for Transmission, which is a gtk3 app.

All the themes I see in the Appearance tool are either gtk2, or gtk3, but not both.

What should I do to make both gtk2 and gtk3 apps look good in LXDE?

Comment: Could you please explain what your OS is, what command you used to install "LXDE", and what themes were listed (other than Clearlooks)?

Comment: I've already installed a lot of themes on my computer, including Ambiance, and I have no idea which were there initially, and which were installed by me. As for the OS, it's Lubuntu.

Comment: Then you should have a theme called Lubuntu-default and I'm pretty sure that that supports both gtk2 and gtk3. I was wondering because you mentioned Clearlooks and that theme is only gtk2. Generally, older themes will be only gtk2 and most themes developed recently will be both.

Comment: Please don't ask essentially the same question in more than one Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a theme that has both gtk2 and gtk3. For example, `sudo apt-get install shimmer-themes` will get you a few themes which support both gtk2 and gtk3. There's also `light-themes` which will get you Ambiance and Radiance.
Incidentally, these themes will work whether you use LXDE or XFCE or Unity.
When you install these themes, they will pull in the necessary gtk engines which you may not have at the moment.
You can see what you will get by using the `-s` flag along with `sudo apt-get install` or by running `apt-cache show _package-name_`.

Comment: I like Arc themes